# Terraform API Gateway HTTP API - Getting the error Insufficient permissions to enable logging

Tags: terraform, terraform-provider-aws

My terraform script for deploying an HTTP API looks like the following. I am getting the following error when I run this -

error creating API Gateway v2 stage: BadRequestException: Insufficient permissions to enable logging

Do I need to add something else to make it work?

```
resource "aws_cloudwatch_log_group" "api_gateway_log_group" {
  name              = "/aws/apigateway/${var.location}-${var.custom_tags.Layer}-demo-publish-api"
  retention_in_days = 7
  tags = var.custom_tags
}

resource "aws_apigatewayv2_api" "demo_publish_api" {
  name = "${var.location}-${var.custom_tags.Layer}-demo-publish-api"
  description = "API to publish event payloads"
  protocol_type = "HTTP"
  tags = var.custom_tags
}

resource "aws_apigatewayv2_vpc_link" "demo_vpc_link" {
  name = "${var.location}-${var.custom_tags.Layer}-demo-vpc-link"
  security_group_ids = local.security_group_id_list
  subnet_ids = local.subnet_ids_list
  tags = var.custom_tags
}

resource "aws_apigatewayv2_integration" "demo_apigateway_integration" {
  api_id           = aws_apigatewayv2_api.demo_publish_api.id
  integration_type = "HTTP_PROXY"
  connection_type = "VPC_LINK"
  integration_uri = var.alb_listener_arn
  connection_id = aws_apigatewayv2_vpc_link.demo_vpc_link.id
  integration_method = "POST"
  timeout_milliseconds = var.api_timeout_milliseconds
}

resource "aws_apigatewayv2_route" "demo_publish_api_route" {
  api_id    = aws_apigatewayv2_api.demo_publish_api.id
  route_key = "POST /api/event"
  target = "integrations/${aws_apigatewayv2_integration.demo_apigateway_integration.id}"
}

resource "aws_apigatewayv2_stage" "demo_publish_api_default_stage" {
  depends_on = [aws_cloudwatch_log_group.api_gateway_log_group]

  api_id = aws_apigatewayv2_api.demo_publish_api.id
  name   = "$default"
  auto_deploy = true
  tags = var.custom_tags

  route_settings {
    route_key = aws_apigatewayv2_route.demo_publish_api_route.route_key
    throttling_burst_limit = var.throttling_burst_limit
    throttling_rate_limit = var.throttling_rate_limit
  }

  default_route_settings {
    detailed_metrics_enabled = true
    logging_level = "INFO"
  }

  access_log_settings {
    destination_arn = aws_cloudwatch_log_group.api_gateway_log_group.arn
    format = jsonencode({ "requestId":"$context.requestId", "ip": "$context.identity.sourceIp"})
  }
}
```

Comment: Have you setup role for the api gateway to allow access to cloudwatch, using [aws_api_gateway_account](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/aws/latest/docs/resources/api_gateway_account)?

Comment: My understanding is that the resource aws_api_gateway_account is for REST APIs only and not applicable for HTTP APIs. If this is not correct, then can you please share the code snippet on how to set this up. Thanks,

Comment: I think you are right. If so, do you have needed permissions to enable logging for http api as shown [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/http-api-logging.html)?

Comment: I tried to add something similar to the Terraform script but could not make it work. That's why I am looking for something that works.

Answer (score 12):

I was stuck on this for a couple of days before reaching out to AWS support. If you have been deploying a lot of HTTP APIs, then you might have run into the same issue where an IAM policy gets very large.

1. Run this AWS CLI command  to find the associated CloudWatch Logs resource policy:
   `aws logs describe-resource-policies`
2. Look for `AWSLogDeliveryWrite20150319`. You'll notice this policy has a large number of associated LogGroup resources. You have three options:

- Adjust this policy by removing some of the potentially unused entries.
- Change the resource list to `"*"`
- You can add another policy. Based on this policy, split the resource records between them.

3. Apply updates via this AWS CLI command:
   `aws logs put-resource-policy`

Here's the command I ran to set resources. Use `"*"` for the policy:

```
aws logs put-resource-policy --policy-name AWSLogDeliveryWrite20150319 --policy-document "{\"Version\":\"2012-10-17\",\"Statement\":[{\"Sid\":\"AWSLogDeliveryWrite\",\"Effect\":\"Allow\",\"Principal\":{\"Service\":\"delivery.logs.amazonaws.com\"},\"Action\":[\"logs:CreateLogStream\",\"logs:PutLogEvents\"],\"Resource\":[\"*\"]}]}"
```

Comment: While this might resolve it (did not try), what's the explanation? Why would it require `*` if resource names are correctly defined?

Comment: Asked AWS support (because I bumped into the same issue). The explanation is that... it's a bug that they are aware of and are _planning_ to fix. The above workaround is indeed exactly what they suggest.

Comment: The "bug" is that policy documents are limited to 5120 characters.  By changing the resource list to "*" your policy document becomes shorter allowing you to add additional resources.  That's why this has the potential to help.

Answer (score 3):

@Marcin Your initial comment about the aws_api_gateway_account was correct. I added the following resources and now it is working fine -

```
resource "aws_api_gateway_account" "demo" {
  cloudwatch_role_arn = var.apigw_cloudwatch_role_arn
}
```

```
data "aws_iam_policy_document" "demo_apigw_allow_manage_resources" {
  version = "2012-10-17"
  statement {
    actions = [
      "logs:DescribeLogGroups",
      "logs:DescribeLogStreams",
      "logs:GetLogEvents",
      "logs:FilterLogEvents"
    ]

    resources = [
      "*"
    ]
  }

  statement {
    actions = [
      "logs:CreateLogDelivery",
      "logs:PutResourcePolicy",
      "logs:UpdateLogDelivery",
      "logs:DeleteLogDelivery",
      "logs:CreateLogGroup",
      "logs:DescribeResourcePolicies",
      "logs:GetLogDelivery",
      "logs:ListLogDeliveries"
    ]

    resources = [
      "*"
    ]
  }
}

data "aws_iam_policy_document" "demo_apigw_allow_assume_role" {
  version = "2012-10-17"
  statement {
    effect = "Allow"
    actions = [
      "sts:AssumeRole"]
    principals {
      type = "Service"
      identifiers = ["apigateway.amazonaws.com"]
    }
  }
}

resource "aws_iam_role_policy" "demo_apigw_allow_manage_resources" {
  policy = data.aws_iam_policy_document.demo_apigw_allow_manage_resources.json
  role = aws_iam_role.demo_apigw_cloudwatch_role.id
  name = var.demo-apigw-manage-resources_policy_name
}

resource "aws_iam_role" "demo_apigw_cloudwatch_role" {
  name = "demo_apigw_cloudwatch_role"
  tags = var.custom_tags
  assume_role_policy = data.aws_iam_policy_document.demo_apigw_allow_assume_role.json
}
```

Comment: the second group of statement.actions is what worked for me

Answer (score 0):

You can route CW logs (aws_cloudwatch_log_group) to **/aws/vendedlogs/*** and it will resolve issue. Or create  **aws_api_gateway_account**